# Problem in uploading new app bundle or apk in play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-build, android-app-bundle

I have a key.jsk file using which I signed my app bundle last time and now I am updating the same app with the same key.jks but getting error as following.

[image]

I matched the SHA1 key which google asks to use sign the app bundle/apk and SHA1 from the key.jks to make sure that my key file is correct one. Both matched but I am not able to upload the app bundle file.

I have just one doubt that I have formatted my work station once. can this occur due to this problem? or there can be other problem. If anyone can help me out that would really helpful. Thnaks a lot in advance.

Comment: - When you formatted your workstation, did you backup the JKS file you used to sign your App Bundles before? You say you're using the same key.jks so I assume you did and are effectively using the same file but since you mention the formatting, just checking.
- You says that you "match the SHA1 key" -- how did you do that? Did you use keytool to print the SHA1 of the certificate in the JKS file? 
- How do you sign the APK? With Gradle? Studio? Manually? Where is your app signing configuration?

Comment: I used a keystore explorer tool which shows the same SHA1 key which is mentioned in the above image and I am using flutter to develop application so I just need to put all credentials and path of jks file in key.properties. So when I try to build release build it uses gradle in the backside.

Comment: Run the following command on your app bundle: `keytool -list -printcert -jarfile bundle.aab` And see if the SHA1 matches the one from the screenshot. It should also match the SHA1 displayed in the App Signing page of the Play Console (under "Upload certificates").

Comment: when I ran the command but it didn't work with -list but it worked with -printcert and shows my jks file details with which I have signed my bundle. Error for -list command is "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file does not exist: C:\Users\user\.keystore".

Comment: So did the printed SHA1 match the one in the error message in Play Console?

Comment: Anyways contacted google Developer support and proceeded with the signing key replacement and now it will be updated in 2 days. Thanks @Pierre